# Assign IBAction to custom navigationBarItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, custom-view

I'm using custom UIViews to as navigationBarItem (like Facebook does it in their iOS app).

```
UIImageView *linkesMenu = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"187menu.png"]];
UIBarButtonItem *barItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:linkesMenu];

barItem.action = @selector(MenuSlider:);
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barItem;
```

I tried this and a couple other things but nothing works really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the image into a button first:

```
UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
UIButton *theButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
theButton.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, theImage.size.width, theImage.size.height);
[theButton setImage:theImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *theBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:theButton];


[theButton addTarget:self action:@selector(MenuSlider:) forControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barItem;
```

Comment: and then I just add the action like I did above?

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Comment: Okay so it does work fine apart from it doesn't do shit :/ I can select the button but it wont perform my IBAction....

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. Glad to see you got it working!